# Adding New XML Tag the code (PHP, HTML)

Tags: php, html, xml

I am having problems extending some code.

I basically need to add a new xml field to the existing ones.

Here is the full code:

**THE HTML FILE**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showRSS(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getrss.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select onchange="showRSS(this.value)">
<option value="">Select an RSS-feed:</option>
<option value="Google">Google News</option>
<option value="MSNBC">MSNBC News</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />
<div id="rssOutput">RSS-feed will be listed here...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**THE PHP FILE**

```
<?php
//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//find out which feed was selected
if($q=="Google")
  {
  $xml=("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml");
  }
elseif($q=="MSNBC")
  {
  $xml=("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml");
  }

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

//get elements from "<channel>"
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

//output elements from "<channel>"
echo("<p><a href='" . $channel_link
  . "'>" . $channel_title . "</a>");
echo("<br />");
echo($channel_desc . "</p>");

//get and output "<item>" elements
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++)
  {
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

  echo ("<p><a href='" . $item_link
  . "'>" . $item_title . "</a>");
  echo ("<br />");
  echo ($item_desc . "</p>");
  }
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi! You can format your code, by putting 4 spaces before each line *(the `{}` button on top of the editor does just that)* -- I've done it for you, this time :-)

Comment: You can also highlight the code and press Ctrl+k.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the formatting help and tips.

Comment: I'll explain my problem a bit more. I have this code that that works:

$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

and I've added another line to get the thumbnail:

$channel_thumbnail= $channel->getElementsByTagName('media:thumbnail')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

But this line above does not work ..

I'm guessing its the media:thumbnail ... if so, what is the way to get the media:thumbnail ?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$item_thumb=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('thumbnail')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```